# X-Men fanfic series about a blue-furred baby who's left on Beast's doorstep

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, fan-fiction

I believe I read this somewhere between 1998 and 2002, possibly on the FanFic Mailing List (FFML), although I was also subscribed to [Blue Believers](https://www.webcitation.org/6dEdqI4ko), a mailing list that was devoted to admirers of blue-furred characters (I think I remember them specifically calling out Beast, Grover, and maybe Cookie Monster). Anyhow, it was a series of stories based around the premise that the X-Men find a child left on their doorstep, a girl covered with blue hair, with a note indicating that it's Beast's daughter. He had not believed himself to have any children, and can't think of any women he's slept with that would fit the timeline, but the X-Men decide to essentially adopt the girl, and the rest of the stories are cute bits of slice-of-life, their domestic life.

The only story I remember distinctly was a horror spoof involving Rogue and the girl's Tickle-Me-Elmo doll. Long story short, Rogue is a bit creeped out by the doll, especially since it keeps showing up in her room. Things get worse when she picks it up one night only to have it tell her to tickle it, and then to tell her to tickle it lower, its voice dropping to a demonic bass. And then she realizes the batteries aren't inserted into it. Ultimately, she wakes up from the nightmare, only to find the doll lying beside her in bed, cue the screaming, followed by the little girl saying that she knew Aunt Rogue had been having bad dreams, so she left her her favorite doll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was "Growing up X" by Darqstar, which apparently expanded to [the X-S Series](https://fanlore.org/wiki/The_X-S_Series).

> Darqstar's **X-S Series** was a popular series about Hank McCoy's adopted daughter, the OC Sikudhani ("Siku") Edna McCoy: "The series that started it all. When Hank meets up with a blue furry baby with no family, what does he do? Adopt her, of course. Well, what would it be like to grow up with the X-Men? These stories might give you some clue..."

The Rogue and Elmo story was ["Nightmare on Elmo Street"](https://web.archive.org/web/20071026133253/http://shifting-sands.alara.net/xs/elmo.htm).

> "Baby!" the doll cried.
>
> She froze. There was something about the doll's voice that... worried her. It was still the same, high, childish voice, but there was an almost... sinister undertone to it. "Baby?" she repeated. "That's not a good thing for a doll to be sayin' not like that."
>
> "Tickle Elmo!" the doll requested again.
>
> She poked the doll's stomach. It vibrated happily, chortling noises emitting from it. "That's better," Rogue said.
>
> "Now tickle Elmo, lower."
>
> She stared into the cloth eyes. "You want me to what?" she asked, her brows furrowing. Something was wrong here.
>
> "Tickle Elmo, *lower*!"
>
> Her fingers moved a little further down the doll's "stomach" and paused. "A little lower, baby!" the doll chortled.
>
> "No way!" she said, louder than she intended. "This isn't funny." She tossed the doll on to the bed. "You're not suppose to say those things!"
>
> "Elmo wants you!" the doll chirped.

....

> Hank yawned. *Why does she have so many stuffed animals and why does she sleep with all of them?* he wondered. "Uhm... Elmo?"
>
> Siku shook her head. "I don' have Elmo." She grinned. "I heard Auntie Rogue havin' a nightmare, so I left him in her room. Elmo will make her feel better!"

After remembering "Blue Believers", I searched for `"blue believers" beast baby`, which brought up [this page of fanfic terms](http://members.tripod.com/fushigi_temple/fanficterms.html), which mentioned "X-S" as a possible tag.

> X-S: aka Growing Up X -- a popular multi-writer series created by Darqstar and concerning the life of one Sikudhani "Siku" Edna McCoy, a child adopted as an infant by Hank "Beast" McCoy and raised by the X-Men.